# Multiple BCC recipients in gmailapp (google apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to send an email to multiple bcc recipents using gmailapp in google apps script.

The following didn't work. I tested it. it seems that only the second recipient bcc2 will get the email. I couldn't find the answer in Google's documents (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)

var bcc = "abc@example.com";

var bcc2 = "xyz@example.com";

GmailApp.sendEmail("",Email_Title, "", {'bcc':bcc, 'bcc':bcc2, htmlBody: Msg });

---

I can get around this by using a for loop

var bcc = ["abc@example.com", "xyz@example.com"];

for (var i = 0; i < bcc.length; i++){}

But this is not ideal to me, as I would find multiple sent email in the sent box, rather than one sent email, with multiple bcc recipients

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the documentation in the link you provided, it states that it needs to be a string, comma-separated list of email addresses. Therefore your code should look like this:

var bcc1and2 = "xyz@example.com,abc@example.com";

GmailApp.sendEmail("",Email_Title, "", {'bcc':bcc1and2, htmlBody: Msg });

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now I wonder why I couldn't get it when I came across with the phase "a string, comma-separated list of email addresses". It is clearly stated in the documentation

Comment: This is a little off topic: I do not see the bcc list in the email I sent (through Apps Script) when I view it from Gmail in my Sent folder. Sending from within Gmail itself always lists the bcc if there is any. Any idea why? How can I see the bcc list?